# This should have been an "invalid edit", right?

Tags: discussion, review, suggested-edits, specific-question

I voted to reject [this edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/4098010) for being "invalid" but was too slow as it was already approved (that's another very annoying issue, this question is not about that). I'm just looking for confirmation, it should have been invalid, right?

The question is about invalid XML and the edit fixes the XML by closing a tag that was missing. In my opinion that is actually answering the question and is thus "an attempt to reply to or comment on the existing post."

Also, "gfvhgvjhvjhjh" is a completely useless comment.

Am I wrong here? This looks like a text book "invalid edit" case with a lousy comment. Why was it approved? It should have been rejected, right?

Comment: Yes, invalid. The error was removed from the code block - a radical changing to the question.

Comment: @juergend I didn't even see that the closing tag was there in the original markdown. That makes it slightly less wrong I guess.

Comment: @juergend I don't see any fixing, looks like just spacing was removed.  The closing tag was there, just not formatted as code, so it was a correction.  However, the edit was too minor and should have been rejected and the 3 reviewers deserve a review ban

Comment: @psubsee2003: Interesting. I don't see the closing tag in *rendered output* of the review.

Comment: @juergend because it is being mistaken for HTML and hidden.  That's what happen when you don't format HTML or HTML-like structures as code.

Comment: This is a bad editor. At best he's doing minor valid edits but usually he cause more harm than good. Should be banned from editing in my opinion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, that's not an invalid edit. But the comment was not correct (And the editor should put proper comments)

It seems like an invalid edit, but not. Because the OP have the full code in his question, but he didn't code formatted the last tag. It's an XML tag, so it won't appear as text in StackOverflow (In general it'll be hidden from outside).

Here is the screenshot of OP's original code and question:

[image: XML Tag Issue]

Comment: So you are saying this was a good edit?

Comment: @psubsee2003: that edit was correct, because he didn't added anything to the original post, He formatted the whole code including the last tag. But his comment is not good, I agree with you in that.

Comment: @psubsee2003 There is a subtle difference between an invalid edit and a not-so-good edit.

Comment: Couldn't disagree more, this is a textbook "too minor" and it should have been improved not approved.  In fairness, it is not the worse edit in the world, but it certainly wasn't a good one.

Comment: @psubsee2003 It changes some code of the OP from hidden to visible. That's a serious improvement. I don't think the rest of the post was so terrible that it was necessarily too minor. It should have been improved indeed, but approving it isn't a bannable offense, in my view.

Comment: @DanielFischer the problem is it sets a precedence for this editor that all he needs to do is go in and make spacing improvements to posts to earn a quick +2 while not care about the rest of the post.  We're trying to improve the quality of edits and the only way is if reviewers start rejecting (or even better improving) too minor edits so editors don't learn bad habits.

Comment: The question wasn't "is this a good edit?" though, it was "is this an invalid edit?", which it is not. I would have skipped, improved or rejected as "too minor" (in order of probability) - rejecting being the last choice because I know it would be in vain.